# To show a set to be sigma finite:

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

If $f : Ω → [0,∞] $ is Borel measurable and if $ \int_{Ω}
f dµ < ∞$,($\mu$ is measure on $\Omega$) then I need to show that,
{ $x ∈ Ω : f(x) < ∞ $}  is a $σ$-finite set.

My attempt:
We can write set,

{ $x ∈ Ω : f(x) < ∞ $} = $\cup_{n\in N}$ {$ x ∈ Ω : f(x) < n $}

I can consider $E_n$= {$ x ∈ Ω : f(x) < n $} and
$F$= {$ x ∈ Ω : f(x) =\infty $}

And $\Omega$= $\cup_{n\in N}$ $E_n$ $\cup$ $F$ and I know that $\mu(F)$=0 which is finite. But I want to show that
$\mu(E_n)$ $<$ $\infty$.

Please help me to show me this last argument and if you feel to modify the above then you are welcome to do so!

Edit: Assuming  $\Omega$ is $\sigma$ finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is false. Take $f \equiv 0$. Unless the original space is sigma finite  we  see that $\{x \in \Omega: f(x) <\infty\}=\Omega$ does not have sigma finite measure. (If the original space is sigma finite there is nothing to prove).

If $f$ takes values in $(0,\infty)$ instead of $[0,\infty)$ then  the result is true. In this case consider $\{x: f(x) >\frac 1n\}$.

Answer for the edited version: If $\mu$ is a sigma finite measure then every measurable subset has sigma finite measure. If $\Omega =\bigcup A_n$ with $\mu (A_n) <\infty$ fo reach $n$ then, for any measurable set $E$ we have $E=\bigcup (E\cap A_n)$ and $\mu (E \cap A_n) <\infty$ for all $n$.

Comment: I agree. But how to claim that $\mu$ ({$ x: f(x)=0 $}) is finite?

Comment: @VatsY I don't understand what you are asking. If $f$ takes values on $(0,\infty)$ then $\{x: f(x)=0\}$ is the empty set so it has measure $0$.

Comment: But if $f$ takes values on $[0,\infty)$. Then?

Comment: I have given a  counter-example to show that the result is false. Do yoy understand that  example? @VatsY

Comment: Now I have modified the question. I am assuming $\Omega$ is $\sigma$ finite. Please see.

Comment: @VatsY I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks:) I got that!